# is there a way in unity3d to play only one audio source at a time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, audio, vuforia

I'm working on an android application with unity 3d, I have two button that play 2 audio sources and I don't want them to play simultaneously.

Comment: Could you show us how you start those audiosources? What should happen? Should the one Pause until the other finished? Should it just stop the other source? ... Please explain a bit more what you are asking exactly

Comment: Like the most basic answer sounds like: `Stop` the one AudioSource before starting the other one...

Comment: when I click on button1 and the audio source1 is playing I want audiosource 1 to stop when I click button 2

Comment: Then call `source1.Stop()` when the button 2 is clicked ?